# php header() set reason phrase took long to benchmark

Tags: php, http, header, response

As per title, for example, an ab test (apache benchmark) on a php file containing only this code managed to do about lesser than 20 request per second on -n 1000 and -c 100.

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 404 My Test Phrase');
```

While setting only the status code does not give the same problem

```
header('HTTP/1.1 404');
```

or

```
http_response_code(404);
```

Any explanation for this behaviour?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please state the PHP version you have installed?

Comment: the installed one is version 5.5.1